# When is it worthwhile to replace working mature code with frameworks+patterns

Tags: java, programming-practices, patterns-and-practices

**Intro/Question**

I fear that frameworks in many cases have become a fashion or trend and are being abused. In many ways people are sacrificing speed just because they want to keep up with every single lib that comes out. I am for a more conservative approach that only makes use of new libraries and frameworks when it absolutely makes sense.

Related: [When NOT to use a framework](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/49488/94281)

**Update/Disclaimer (May 18, 2017)**

I've come to the conclusion that rapid application development, ease, and maintainability are the targets. So frameworks (new and old) should be used  provided they help in reaching a final product quicker. Only when special cases exist (actual measurable performance issues) should we switch to custom code... or when the project itself is legacy and the cost of completely rewriting are too high.

**Case**

We have a Tomcat6 Servlet production that has been ongoing development since 2008 and there are many hours of work behind it. The code is very mature but it does not use any frameworks.

A new team member loves using frameworks and patterns for everything. Except for the love of frameworks, they also love cutting edge new releases and even proposed migrating from Tomcat6 to somethiong newer (JBOSS,GLASSFISH, or TOMCAT8).

I would never move a core production service to a container/server/web-server that just came out.

Not against refactoring code to keep it clean though!

I am against adding frameworks and patterns that add delay to production code servicing thousands of requests per second.

**Serialization to stream (JSON/XML) while maintaining backwards compatibility**

When a request comes, we produce both XML and JSON documents containing data related to the request params.

Since we maintain backwards compatibility for older clients changes must not break older support. Since we also support both JSON and XML, we make use of the Jackson but also KXML libraries.

For both formats we have 2 different serialization methods that use the **streaming API**. Except for being faster, I also find it is MUCH more flexible for maintaining backwards compatibility.

I like to use a sysyem of Major and Minor version. All minor changes to the backend that cause changes to the serialized document I add with IF statements in the serialization method. Once quite a few changes have accomulated (over 1 year), we add a new serialization method. So, all requests specifying version=1.00 to 1.99 are sent to serializeJSON1. All requests using version 2 to 2.99 are sent to serializeJSON2.

I've heard the argument that we should use ANNOTATIONS and MAP to objects. 
I find this very distastefull as I have read streaming is the fastest.

The streaming API allows you to make necessary changes on the fly while MAPPING would require to store multiple versions of the same data as different objects, or jump through other hoops.

```
 output.startTag(null, TagTable.PRODUCT);

 output.startTag(null, TagTable.ID);
 output.text(ID);
 output.endTag(null, TagTable.ID);

 output.startTag(null, TagTable.DESCRIPTION);

 if (locale != null && Translations.containsKey(locale) && version >= 1)
     output.text(this.DescriptionURL + "/" + locale);
 else
     output.text(this.DescriptionURL);

 output.endTag(null, TagTable.LONGDESCRIPTION);

 if (version >= 1 && version < 1.5) {
     output.startTag(null, TagTable.POPULARITY);
     output.text(String.valueOf((int) this.pop));
     output.endTag(null, TagTable.POPULARITY);
 } else if (version >= 1.5) {
     output.startTag(null, TagTable.RATING);
     output.text(String.valueOf((int) this.rating));
     output.endTag(null, TagTable.RATING);
 }
```

In the specific 3 cases above I really don't see the point to replace working mature code with frameworks/libs/patterns that may add additional overhead and cost additional development time.

So, when is it worthwhile to replace working mature code with frameworks+patterns??

Comments?

**Update: Some benchmarks**

For the first two examples posted previously, using REST and HASHMAPs does not make overly that big a difference in performance but does make the code more readable.

Now for the more interesting issue about serialization when used in a hotspot.
Since the actual servlet in question had too much other code I made a toy example to test streaming vs mapping. The code is available at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21781540/

By all means test it, change it, run it.

What is very interesting is that the Just in time optimizer in java ends up making the difference negligable over time. So, here is how the percentage between mapping and streaming changes the more iterations there are.

```
Iter    Stream  Mapping
0       36,71%  63,29%
20      44,75%  55,25%
40      45,65%  54,35%
60      45,95%  54,05%
80      46,24%  53,76%
100     47,09%  52,91%
120     47,09%  52,91%
140     47,37%  52,63%
160     47,64%  52,36%
180     47,92%  52,08%
200     47,64%  52,36%
220     47,92%  52,08%
240     47,92%  52,08%
260     47,92%  52,08%
280     48,19%  51,81%
300     48,45%  51,55%
320     48,45%  51,55%
340     48,45%  51,55%
360     48,45%  51,55%
380     48,45%  51,55%
400     48,45%  51,55%
1000    48,72%  51,28%
2000    49,24%  50,76%
3000    49,24%  50,76%
4000    49,49%  50,51%
5000    49,75%  50,25%
6000    49,75%  50,25%
7000    49,75%  50,25%
8000    49,75%  50,25%
9000    49,75%  50,25%
```

I also re-ran one more time have first 20 iterations more detailed:

```
0   39,76%  60,24%
1   41,18%  58,82%
2   40,83%  59,17%
3   40,12%  59,88%
4   40,48%  59,52%
5   40,83%  59,17%
6   40,83%  59,17%
7   40,83%  59,17%
8   40,48%  59,52%
9   40,12%  59,88%
10  41,52%  58,48%
11  42,53%  57,47%
12  42,86%  57,14%
13  42,86%  57,14%
14  43,18%  56,82%
15  43,50%  56,50%
16  43,50%  56,50%
17  43,82%  56,18%
18  43,82%  56,18%
19  43,82%  56,18%
20  44,75%  55,25%
```

After 10,000 iterations (or calling JSON generation code 1000 times) here is the screenshot from VisualVM profiling ([visualVM snapshot NPS file](https://db.tt/AFRBCjbI)):

[image]

So, if this optimization behavior holds up in Tomcat servlets as well, it means there really is **no point NOT to use mapping** (and many other convenience functions/libs since the JVN will optimize over time).

**Conclusions**

Based on the answers/comments, I think at the end of the day whether to rewrite working production code is affected by business requirement, and specific cost-benefit analysis for each project.

Based on the benchmarking, it turns out avoiding some libs/frameworks may make no difference in the long run due to JIT JVM optimizations.

**Update: After leaving code running all night**

[image]

After 275,137 iterations and approximately 30,000 MS:

```
Mapping -   19,80%
Streaming -  80,20%
```

I really wonder what JIT optimizations happen here and whether the behavior holds for a servlet.

Comment: Not necessarily. Get back to us with numbers when you've profiled both implementations.

Comment: Frameworks do not always add delay. More often than not, frameworks are written and optimized by specialists dedicated to their function. These specialists will often do better than you will.

Comment: "It would only add overhead (additional MS delay for every request)" "even if they added 5 to 10 MS" If this estimate is of the cost of adding extra layers of method calls, then it's too high by a factor of a million.

Comment: The estimate is still almost certainly too high by a factor of a million. I'll let you profile and test that though.

Comment: @maythesource I debated whether to point it out, but I thought I should, in case it's not obvious to you. Your response to being told that your cost estimate was too high by a factor of a million, which it was, was to call the messenger a troll. I hope that you will exercise greater level of objectivity in the future.

Comment: I've updated the question to follow the guidelines more closely. If need be I will further update. Obviously if someone could run benchmarks on similar scenarios in order to help out that would be very appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: The questions not asked here are what business purpose would be served by rewriting the code and whether or not achieving that purpose justifies the cost of the rewrite.

Comment: The code you are defending is pretty much indefensible.  Iterating and checking is error prone and slow.  Why do you think that hashing is slow?  A String's hash value is cached, so it is only calculated once.  I think you should listen to your team member.  It seems he is bringing in some valuable knowledge.  Or you can drive him out and continue in blissful ignorance.

Comment: @kevin cline From what I understand your commenting on the first example only- the synch with sdb. You do have a point, though this code will be changed when there is time - the owner wants new features continuously.If we consider using a REST lib better for readability, that makes 2/3. Still not sold about changing the serialization mechanism of the web service.

Comment: "Will update this with profiling/benchmarking information when we're done with first tests." It's been 4 days since the need to test your assumptions about "delay" was brought to your attention. The fact that you have not done so speaks for itself.

Comment: @user16764 lay off or do some tests yourself. People also have to do other stuff that takes priority. All you have been doing the last days is attacking. If you were really interested in helping you wouldn't be picking fights.

Comment: It is your own responsiblity to back up your claim that adding a framework would add MILLISECONDS. The real reason you haven't done so is because it's more politically convenient for you not to. You've had 4 days to do so, and the fact that you've labeled an attempt to point this out as "attacking" says a lot about your ability to examine your own position. A huge part of your position is based on this untested and almost certainly way-off cost estimate, so this is not exactly a bit of unrelated trivia. I feel sorry for the people who have to work with you.

Comment: You expect a user to drop everything else mid-week and produce results simply because your screaming and yelling. If it should be done, it should be done right, and that takes time in order to post correct results. I have mentioned that you could help out and contribute by providing tests and sharing results to help both me, and other users. Your more interested in bullying people and blaming. If you notice @Telastyn also pointed out things, and I agreed with some of them.

Comment: @user16764 It says a lot about you the way you behave on stackexchange. I have work that takes priority. If I'm going to profile and compare I'm going to do it on the weekend when I have time. The code is running, so this isn't a high priority issue or a bug that needs immediate fixing. Also, if it turns out I'm wrong I will also admit that when I post the results. But again, the code to compare has to be done right. Also, your completely ignoring the question of whether stable production code should be changed - why don't you go to banks and tell them to replace their legacy code?

Comment: @user16764 So have some patience. I'm pretty sure we will all be enlightened and then you can examine my different implementation(s) and find various other things to point out. Atleast my hope is you will provide constructive comments when it comes to comparing different implementations, and if at the end of the day IF I'm wrong, and the moderny implementation is not that slow, I still win by learning something and improving :P.

Comment: @maythesource Pointing out where you're wrong *is* helping in a constructive way. I'm sorry you've failed to recognize that. As of now, your position remains based on an unexamined estimate that's almost certainly been inflated by a factor of a million. You can label attempts to point this out as "bullying" instead of, oh, *revising the estimate* if you want to.

Comment: @kevincline "Or you can drive him out and continue in blissful ignorance." His behavior in this thread suggests that that's exactly what he's going to do.

Comment: @user16764 Did you not notice that I said there would be code/testing by Monday? You want me to agree with you without having tested it? If your in such a hurry could you do it to help out? I've asked you multiple times and you ignore that. You ignore a lot of what I say in my replies. So what's your reason for continuing the discussion until then? Even if your right do you think your behavior is appropriate? Even if your right, what exactly are you after here?

Comment: "Even if your right, what exactly are you after here?" I expect you to drop your performance claims until you have data to defend them. That also includes the hashcode vs iteration one.

Comment: @user16764 There is one thing you don't know or didn't consider. The serialization is a HOTSPOT. Yes, serializing 1 product object with mapping vs streaming API will have small difference. But, catalog size is 1000 to 1500 elements (max). Additionally, we have 500+ requests (per second- monitored via varnish) on max traffic hours. So, that negligible overhead difference has now been multiplied by 500,000 to 750,000 times. Remember hotspots? "additional MS delay for every request" - now do you understand what per every object PER every request means?

Comment: @maythesource Yes, that does seem more reasonable now. That is, however, exactly the situation where you actually need to do performance tests instead of assuming which implementation is faster (and by how much). I look forward to seeing them on Monday.

Comment: @user16764 Added some preliminary results. Very interesting... I do wonder how JVM flavor will affect this (OpenJDK on centos vs JREs), as well as if running the two functions in separate applications will play a role.

Comment: @maythesource.com I think Eric Evans once mentioned in a presentation he made that only build something from scratch if the cost of maintaining the old system is higher than building a new one.

Comment: @maythesource Well, you've definitely done the right thing here. Now, your decisions on "which implementation should I choose" will be much better informed, and backed up by data. Keep in mind that with modern architectures and compilers, it is  often extremely difficult to tell "which implementation of this CPU bound task is faster" without profiling: for another example, see: [Larger Code is Still Faster](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/212904/16764)

Comment: @user16764 This makes me understand C low level guys who hate giving power away (memory manegement, etc.). Also: "premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They say

> a bird in the hand is better than 2 in the bush

Applied here, I take it to mean its better to have something that works and is maintainable than to tear it all down for some fantasy daydream of "but it'll be vaguely better if we use X Y or Z cool new technology for the sake of using the cool new technology".

I mean, you could have rewritten it in a functional language a few years ago, or Ruby on Rails a couple of years ago, or Node.js a year ago or... whatever comes along next that gets attention in the technical blogosphere. None of these things would create you a stable product that satisfies the 'must use new stuff' people as they will be considered old technologies before they're even finished and they'll want to re-rewrite!

So I have to ask "what's your problem?". You have good code that might be a bit mucky here and there, but in my extensive experience, when you start a big rewrite you end up with code that's a bit mucky (often quickly implemented due to inexperience with the tooling or done under time pressure that you will come back to and fix up nicely, promise.)

When you use a framework is when you are doing a new project and you want a load of code written for you, that's the time to go framework, to re-use all that boring boilerplate that you'd have to write yourself. You never go for a framework because its there to be used, especially when you have an existing framework that you know (even if you don't call it a framework because its grown by itself, it's effectively still one).

One thing to note, I do find a lot of the people who insist on using any kind of new technology want to for 1 of 2 reasons: they either want to boost their CV, or they do not want to learn the existing technology you use (after all, learning tech x is way more fun than actually doing work on existing product). I treat all calls with suspicion as in either case their intention is not in the best interest of the product or the business.

Heavy refactoring...that's a different story, and usually a good one.

Comment: Joel Spolsky had a lot to say about rewriting production code [way back in 2000](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html)

Comment: @DanPichelman true then as it is today.

Answer (score 17):

Ugh. Some points:

- **"I have read it is fastest".** Don't be a cultist. Think for yourself. Measure for yourself. Personally, if you're generating XML by hand, I would question your sanity.
- **who knows what bugs lurk** It is foolish and shortsighted to fear what you do not know. This leads to "not invented here" syndrome and quickly being passed by programmers who had the courage to learn better tools.
- **frameworks hinder performance** Runtime performance is very often cheap. Programmer time is not. The trade off here is that these frameworks may add a slight performance penalty in exchange for saving you a bunch of time writing and maintaining the code. In the XML example, if you had used annotations and a serialization framework, you wouldn't have to write and test your own XML formatter (read: cost your company all that money).

Look - code that is done and tested is good. And certainly, adopting a framework because "that's what you're supposed to do" is a good way to make bad software. But these examples strike me as simply you making excuses to avoid change. Yes, change is scary. Yes, change can lead to bugs. But change is necessary to eliminate inefficiency, and improve your ability to maintain and extend your code.

Comment: +1 Indeed, some good points. So, for the JACKSON example how would you go about using mappings/annotations to create something that is both clear but also backwards compatible? The only thing I can think of is creating different classes with different constructors. Based on the requested version create a different object, and call the automated serialize method.

Comment: Most serialization frameworks have either a dispatch behavior (use A if version 1.x, etc.) or conditional sort of things (include this property if version 2.x, etc.). The main point is I don't know your problem (or Java frameworks) well enough to say. I would prototype a solution and see which solves my problem better.

Comment: In relation to "Personally, if you're generating XML by hand, I would question your sanity.". It seems there are more insane people if you look at http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5bstax%5d%20writing and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10299124/reading-and-writing-an-xml-in-java

Comment: i updated my jar something broke. another library uses a newer version of a library i use ... but the newer version fixed a bug i was relying on ... no silver bullets ...

Comment: @maythesource.com: Your code may work but it is naively written, overly verbose, and expensive to maintain.  You should listen carefully when your new team member proposes changes.  Or you can ignore him until he leaves in frustration, continuing in blissful ignorance until something or someone wakes up your manager and you go away too.

Comment: "programmer time is not" - considering the amount of time that would be spent rewriting. If they already had a framework, then this is a good argument to prevent a rewrite to something custom, but if they start with the custom solution, this is a poor argument in favour of using one.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - Consider the amount of time spent maintaining that custom framework. Need windows 8 support? Oh, that's a week of development and testing (about $5000). There's certainly a point where the rewrite cost would be more than the maintenance cost before end of life, but support is a non-trivial expense, especially compared to runtime performance.

Comment: I think every case is different. We're talking about a servlet... more applicable would be how easily does one make this system distributable on a cloud to handle much more traffic... or how easily can you add a new document format if client moves to bison (for example).

Comment: @Telastyn true, but then there's the cost of the framework too - need Windows 8 support and it doesn't work already, that's much more than $5000, if it does then you need to cost testing to ensure it works. Note a custom one will be as well-known internally as a "standard" one. There's also a hidden cost in that you have to pay to test your code against upgrades, and I've been in situations where the company would not upgrade because of incompatibilities. Its all relative but the point here is that it is better to stick with what you have rather than what you might have.

Comment: @gbjbaanb - sometimes it is, sometimes it isn't. You can't just always say that what you have today is better or else we'd all be toggling switches on vacuum tubes.

Comment: @Telastyn I rather think that comparing vacuum tubes to transistors is not quite in the same league as some framework some guys wrote and released as open source compared to some other framework some other guys wrote. (and sometimes staying put is the right thing to do, see 'new coke' for the classic example)

Comment: @gbjbaanb "Note a custom one will be as well-known internally as a 'standard' one" -- Not to anyone you hire afterwards.

Comment: There is an issue though that you need people versed/experienced with the framework. If something is plain old code it required reading. If something is using framework XYZ Version x.y.z the next guy either needs to be a XYZ Version x.y.z expert or read documentation on the specific framework. On the other hand, learning custom code won't help someone in the next job except for maybe seeing a few ideas. Learning a lib/framework can be applied to the next job (til the framework changes radically & knowledge=deprecated, struts1 vs struts2) or that framework is considered dead.